# Android Map Fragment Inconsistent Camera/Markers

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, mapfragment

My map fragment seems to be having some issues. I'm calling it in my 2nd activity from the first which is my custom adapter set to a `recyclerView`.

I am adding 2 markers to the map from coordinates that change depending on the item clicked in the adapter.

What I want to happen is for the camera to move the map to show each pair of coordinates with padding around them, as in the image below.

[image]
The problem is that it only appears this way maybe 10% of the time. The rest of the time the map is zoomed all the way out like in the below image.

[image]

Am I not building my bounds or moving the camera correctly or getting the coordinates correctly or what? I can't figure it out. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? This is how I am sending the lat/lng from my adapter:

```
holder.routeinfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, RouteDetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("lat1", routeList.get(position).getLat1());
            intent.putExtra("lng1", routeList.get(position).getLng1());
            intent.putExtra("lat2", routeList.get(position).getLat2());
            intent.putExtra("lng2", routeList.get(position).getLng2());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

And here is my `onMapReady()` from my `RouteDetailsActivity`:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    Double lat1 = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("lat1");
    Double lng1 = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("lng1");

    Double lat2 = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("lat2");
    Double lng2 = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("lng2");

    //Origin Marker
    LatLng origin = new LatLng(lat1, lng1);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(origin)
            .title("Origin"));

    //Destination Marker
    LatLng destination = new LatLng(lat2, lng2);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(destination)
            .title("Destination"));

    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    builder.include(origin);
    builder.include(destination);
    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 5));
}
```

Comment: Can you post the origin and destination coordinates that caused the output as in your second image?

Comment: @Much Overflow Sure, both maps should be showing the same set of points, which are:  `lat1=29.425745,  lng1=-98.4861562` and `lat2=29.5215668, -98.5022129`

Comment: I added code showing how I am sending the coordinates to my map fragment. Hmm this is a real puzzler, if the points are accessible, I'm guessing it has something to do with the rendering of the map. Do I need to clear the map before loading it each time or what? I'll try and do some more research.

Comment: you may try with this.. used animateCamera instead of moveCamera... i.e. use mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 5));

Comment: I've tried `animateCamera();` already, doesn't seem to make a difference.